# How does one use the with inspect in Agda?

Tags: pattern-matching, coq, type-inference, agda

I'm trying to reproduce a very simple coq proof from Programming foundations in agda, and was told I need to use the with inspect to prove a contradction from the pattern match on the (bool) decideablity of a string with itself.  I'm getting the below error, and the documentation doesn't even give a proper program using with with inspect.  Why is this type inference incorrect, and how can I resolve my error?

```
module Maps where

open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality using (_≡_; refl; cong; subst; trans; sym; inspect)
open import Data.String using (_++_; _==_; _≟_; String)
open import Data.Bool using (T; Bool; true; false; if_then_else_)

-- Coq-- Theorem eqb_string_refl : forall s : string, true = eqb_string s s.
eqbstringrefl' : (s : String) →  true ≡ (s == s)
eqbstringrefl' s with inspect (s == s) 
... | false with≡ eq = {!!}
... | true with≡ eq  = {!!}
```

The (s == s) is highlighted red and yields the following error

```
Bool !=< (x : _A_70) → _B_71 x of type Set
when checking that the inferred type of an application
Bool
matches the expected type
(x : _A_70) → _B_71 x
```

Answer (score 2):

The `inspect` function in the standard library has the following type:

```
inspect : ∀ {A : Set a} {B : A → Set b}
          (f : (x : A) → B x) (x : A) → Reveal f · x is f x
```

As you can see, it takes two explicit arguments: a function `f` and a value `x`. The [user manual](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.1/language/with-abstraction.html#the-inspect-idiom) has a section on how to use the inspect idiom, specifically the second example uses essentially the same definition of `inspect` as the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

The standard library has a [`README` dealing with the `inspect` idiom](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/README.Inspect.html).